# http post not responding on windows server 2012

Tags: windows, http, post, get, http-headers

I am working on a software that use http post to do some things. The http post work perfect everywhere but in windows server 2012 it need specific header order. I am attaching fiddler screenshots. In the screenshots you can see that if i change header order it stop working.

Specific order works:

[image: Image1]

Changing host to other line not working:

[image: Image2]

Comment: Are you implementing the client that sends the POST, implementing the server that receives the POST, or both?  Define "stops working" exactly. What is the client actually doing (or not doing) when it sends the POST with the "wrong" header order? What is the server actually doing (or not doing) when it receives the POST with the "wrong" header order?

Comment: I am implementing the client that sends the POST. Client works everywhere  but not on windows server 2012. Windows server 2012 need specific header order. Maybe there is an option somewhere to disable it. When i send headers in different order on windows server 2012 i don' t get any result. Is like blocking http before sending to server.

Comment: *Windows* does not process HTTP posts, an HTTP server app does instead. So which server app are you actually using? IIS? Apache? Something else? It is very unlikely that any commonly-used HTTP-conforming server would exhibit this problem, so it makes me wonder if you are maybe using some lesser-used 3rd party server app instead, and it has a processing bug in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header order is not important for headers of different names (the order of headers with the same name does matter):

[RFC 2616 Section 4.2 Message Headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2)

> **The order in which header fields with differing field names are received is not significant**. However, it is "good practice" to send general-header fields first, followed by request-header or response-header fields, and ending with the entity-header fields.

[RFC 7230 Section 3.2.2 Field Order](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2):

> **The order in which header fields with differing field names are received is not significant**.  However, it is good practice to send header fields that contain control data first, such as Host on requests and Date on responses, so that implementations can decide when not to handle a message as early as possible.  A server MUST NOT apply a request to the target resource until the entire request header section is received, since later header fields might include conditionals, authentication credentials, or deliberately misleading duplicate header fields that would impact request processing.

If the HTTP server does not work correctly when the `Host` header is not in a desired order, then it is in violation of the HTTP specification, as the header can appear in any order and the server must be prepared to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the above information. But the problem is that i am developing a software that use http post. I can' t set http post order on the code and the specific problem appear only on windows server 2012. Windows 7 works fine without specific order.

Comment: Why don't you have control over the headers? Are you using a pre-made HTTP library?  It is very unlikely that any of the commonly-used HTTP libraries would put the `Host` header at the bottom of the header list, like you showed.

Comment: i am using UBOT with http post plugin. The strange thing is that on windows 7 it works with Host on bottom.

Comment: UBOT is a client-side technology. It sounds like you are having a server-side issue.  Unless the server is actually responding, and the plugin is not handling it correctly.  I would expect the plugin to send the headers in the same order no matter what version of Windows you are POSTing from.

Comment: I have tested your screenshot requests with my Fiddler, and there were no problems with `Host` being on the top or bottom, the server responded as expected in both cases (but I'm not running on Windows Server 2012). But that is with GET requests. You are having problems with POST requests instead, but you have not shown what your requests actually look like. Please edit your question to show the actual requests (no screenshots, copy/paste the raw data instead) so people can try to reproduce your problem. Use Wireshark or Fiddler to capture what the plugin is actually sending and receiving.